# Custom taskbar per virtual desktop on Windows

Tags: windows, taskbar, windows-11, desktop, virtual-desktop

I'm trying to separate applications for work from applications for free time on Windows 11.

My initial approach was to organize the windows for these apps in separate virtual desktops. However, virtual desktops do not allow me to do the following:

1. **Customize the pinned applications in the task bar.** Ideally, I would like to pin work related apps in the task bar of my work desktop (e.g., Slack) and personal apps in the task bar of my free time desktop (e.g., Steam). I do not want to mix them.
2. **Customize the desktop shortcuts.** Similarly, I would like to customize the shortcuts on each desktop.

I have searched for third-party virtual desktop managers and tried the following two:

- [Dexpot](https://dexpot.de/?lang=en)
- [VirtuaWin](https://virtuawin.sourceforge.io/)

Unfortunately, they seem to lack these features too.

On Windows 11, is there any way to have multiple custom task bars/shortcuts for a single account?

Answer (score 1):

The best I could do was to unpin all apps from the taskbar, then only the open apps will be on the taskbar per desktop.